# Pandas DataFrames add square brackets to specific column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to add sqaure backets to specif column values.

like in DataFrame if I have 2 columns

1. Name
2. country

   ```
   Name               country

   Ali                UK,USA
   Sara               UK,Canada
   Tom                Australia,Canada
   ```

how I can add the square brackets to the values of column country.

Like:

```
       Name               country

   Ali                [UK,USA]
   Sara               [UK,Canada]
   Tom                [Australia,Canada]
```

Comment: `df['country'] = "[" + df['country'] + "]"`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for convert strings to lists:

```
df['country'] = df['country'].str.split(',')
```

If no missing values also working:

```
df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
```